A space homeomorphic to product of unit circle and sphere in $\mathbb R^3$
Let $X=\{(\alpha, e^{i\theta}\overline{\alpha}, e^{i\theta}, \overline{\beta}-e^{i\theta}\beta) : |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1, \theta \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathbb{C}^4$, where $\overline{\alpha}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $\alpha$.  My question is if $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^3=\{(c, \alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1, |c|=1\}$ or not.
Intuitively, this feels to be not true. I tried using the approach via fundamental groups. Because if two spaces are homeomorphic, then the induced map between fundamental groups is an isomorphism of groups. So, if the fundamental groups of $X$ and $S^1 \times S^3$ (which is $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ in this case) are not isomorphic, then the spaces are not homeomorphic.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP has asked the same question twice: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4976241/349785
